# Can i override the output of the mssql.Request.execute method to be like older versions in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, extends

I am in the process up upgrading some libraries in a nodejs project.  When i took over this project, it was using the mssql library versioned at 2.5.0.  I am attempting to update it to version 9.1.1

In the earlier version code like the following

```
const sql = _db.request('mydbname');
sql.execute('stored_proc_name', (err, result) => {
    for (ix = 0; ix < result.length, ix++) {
       console.log(result[i].columnName);
    }
})
```

would work.  The responding object was an array of records. Sometimes it was a multi dimensional array if there were multiple recordsets returned.  It also had a parameters object that returned output parameters.

The new version returns an object with a recordsets, recordset and other objects.  To do the code above, I would have to change to `result.recordsets.length` and `result.recordsets[i].columnName`

This would require extensive changes to the project.  Is there a way to override the output?

I tried to do this code in my wrapper that controls my connection pool (this is what is instanciated as _db in the above code and when passed the `request('mydbname')` gets back the mssql.Request object that executes the code.

```
class DBRequest extends mssql.Request {

    _execute (procedure, callback) {
        const result = super._execute(procedure, (err, result) => {
            callback(null, result)
        });
    }
}
```

This resulted in the same output as the 9.1.1 version currently does.